# Python - Bayesian Optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, bayesian, colorama

I am completely lost with the following code. Basically I am using Anaconda in order to create a ML model. However I can not figure out the issue here. If anyone can help, thank you so much! I installed and updated all relevant packages, but colorama keeps causing an issue. I am trying to execute the following code, which always gives me the error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'just_fix_windows_console' from 'colorama'

Executed code:

```
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

def fcv(max_depth, gamma, min_child_weight, subsample, colsample_bytree, learning_rate, num_boost_round):
  params = {"objective":'reg:squarederror', "max_depth":int(max_depth), 'gamma':gamma, 'min_child_weight':min_child_weight, 'subsample':subsample, "colsample_bytree":colsample_bytree, "learning_rate":learning_rate}
  cv_results=xgb.cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=params, nfold=10, num_boost_round=int(num_boost_round), early_stopping_rounds=10, metrics='rmse', as_pandas=True)
  return -cv_results['test-rmse-mean'].min() 


dict_cv = {
          'max_depth': (2, 12),
          'gamma': (0.001, 10.0),
          'min_child_weight': (0, 20),
          'subsample': (0.4, 1.0),
          'colsample_bytree': (0.4, 1.0),
          'learning_rate': (0.1, 1.0),
          'num_boost_round' :(30, 100)
          }

XGB_BO = BayesianOptimization(fcv, dict_cv) #Creating the optimizer
XGB_BO.maximize(init_points=10, n_iter=40, acq='ei', xi=0.0) #Running optimization!


Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\ehler\Documents\Masterarbeit\Codes\MAcoding_v5.ipynb Zelle 34 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization
      2 # Gradient Boosting Machine
      3 def gbm_cl_bo(max_depth, max_features, learning_rate, n_estimators, subsample):

File c:\Users\ehler\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bayes_opt\__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from .bayesian_optimization import BayesianOptimization, Events
      2 from .domain_reduction import SequentialDomainReductionTransformer
      3 from .util import UtilityFunction

File c:\Users\ehler\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bayes_opt\bayesian_optimization.py:5, in <module>
      1 import warnings
      3 from bayes_opt.constraint import ConstraintModel
----> 5 from .target_space import TargetSpace
      6 from .event import Events, DEFAULT_EVENTS
      7 from .logger import _get_default_logger

File c:\Users\ehler\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bayes_opt\target_space.py:4, in <module>
      1 import warnings
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from .util import ensure_rng, NotUniqueError
      5 from .util import Colours
      8 def _hashable(x):
...
   (...)
     44     :return: x_max, The arg max of the acquisition function.
     45     """

ImportError: cannot import name 'just_fix_windows_console' from 'colorama' (c:\Users\ehler\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\colorama\__init__.py)
```

I installed and updated all relevant packages, but colorama keeps causing an issue.

Instead it should execute the Bayesian Optimization

Comment: `just_fix_windows_console` function was added in the latest version of the `colorama==0.4.6`, you can just try `pip install -U colorama`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. however it tells me that this is already satsified. However it shows the path at the end of the error. might it be installed "the wrong place"? Error Message: ImportError: cannot import name 'just_fix_windows_console' from 'colorama' (c:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\colorama\__init__.py)

Comment: Try to uninstall and install it again with correct env. You can see the first line of the [`changelog`](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst)

Comment: I tried it too. Unfortunately the same thing still happens. Same error, even after reinstalling?

Comment: It's hard to debug the issue with the information you have provided in your question. There could be multiple issues that could go wrong here. Maybe env mismatch (or) some other library replacing the version etc.,, Maybe create a new library and install `colorama` at the end? Check if the script or notebook is using which environement to run the code. These are few things I'll look out for.

Comment: Can you provide a complete stack trace? (Edit it into the question.) It will include additional useful debugging information.

Comment: I updated the question. I am not sure if that might help?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error simply by running: "from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization". However I can not solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue between colorama and bayesian-optimization,
the way I finally managed to get over it (Thanks to Frank Fletcher on Springboard Technical support mentor) was to create a new environment and run this part :

```
conda create -n bayes -c conda-forge python=3.8 seaborn bayesian-optimization\
 lightgbm catboost jupyter
```

well I was using LightGBM it should work with XGBoost as well,
(xgboost instead of lightgbm in code above)